No provider of jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider was found
I'm getting the error below. Any idea how to fix this?
Spring boot version: 3.3.0. Java version: 17.
Error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No provider of jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider was found
at jakarta.mail.util.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:61)
at jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider.provider(StreamProvider.java:199)
at jakarta.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:257)
at jakarta.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:383)
at jakarta.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:423)

Java code:
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties()));

pom.xml:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


Eclipse angus-mail is the successor of the sum mail impl(com.sun.mail:jakarta-mail), replace your sun mail dependency with the following.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
    <artifactId>angus-mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>

And you also need jakarta-acitivation in the dependencies when using Jakarta Mail API.
Check my example with the custom config from scratch without Spring Boot: https://github.com/hantsy/spring6-sandbox/blob/master/mail/
But for Spring Boot users,  the simplest way is to utilize mail starter, and inject JavaMailSender directly into your application to send an email.

I tried to replace the dependency, but I'm getting this error now.


I am not sure you have updated your deps, when using Eclipse Angus, all namespaces are updated to org.eclipse.angus.


I tried to replace the dependency, but I'm getting this error now. java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html cannot be cast to class jakarta.activation.DataContentHandler (com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html and jakarta.activation.DataContentHandler are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Don't mix the old activation.jar with the new jaf-api and angus-activation jars.  There is a bug where mixing the old com.sun classes with the org.eclipse classes doesn't work correctly.  See Using Jakarta mail and Javamail in the same runtime.
The 4 dependencies you want are:
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
  <artifactId>angus-activation</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
  <artifactId>angus-mail</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>

